# Are Processing time , Execution time and Burst time the same?

Tags: algorithm, cpu, scheduling

I have a set of processes with arrival times and CPU execution times given in
milliseconds. A process with a larger priority number has a higher priority.

| Process | Arrival Time | Execution Time | Priority |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | 0 | 06 | 1 |
| P2 | 5 | 04 | 2 |
| P3 | 7 | 07 | 5 |
| P4 | 9 | 09 | 3 |
| P5 | 10 | 02 | 4 |

is this CPU Execution time, Processing time and burst time same ?

Comment: I suppose the question is whether these times include waiting time (or IO time) or not. I don't believe there's a standard definition of any of them, so you need to ask whoever is using these jargon words to say more clearly what they mean.

Comment: Since Burst time is the total time taken by the process for its execution on the CPU, I think it is same as execution time. But what is this Processing time ?